# Understanding string arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to understand this particular line of code.

I'm having trouble comprehending why there are 3 assignment statements needed for this.  I figure it is the minimum necessary, I just can't seem to follow it with my mind.

If someone could take me through what each line of this does, in english, that would be fantastic.

Thanks.

```
void to_upper(char *word) {

  int index = 0;

  while (word[index] != '\0') {
    word[index] = toupper(word[index]);
    index++;
  }
}

int length(char *word) {

  int index=0;

  while (word[index] != '\0')
    index++;
  return index;
}

void reverse(char *word) {
  int index, len;
  char temp;
  len = length(word);
  for (index=0; index<len/2; index++) {
    temp = word[index];
    word[index] = word[len-1-index];
    word[len-1-index] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's more than one line of code.  Exactly what part are you confused about? Presuming that you're asking about `reverse`, how would *you* do it with fewer assignments?

Comment: `to_upper` and `length` are not really part of what you're asking about, are they?

Comment: Why do you have a custom `length` instead of just using `strlen`?

Comment: Are you talking about the swapping code? Can you think of a way to swap without the temp variable? (possible in this case but less readable, and error prone..)

Comment: On the first iteration, the triple assignment swaps the first and last characters; on the second iteration, it swaps the first+1 and last-1 characters; and on subsequent iterations keeps on swapping pairs of characters similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you understand the `length` and `to_upper` parts of your code as they are basically c++ 101 stuff.

```
//Well, just be the title, I would assume this function reverses a string, lets continue.
void reverse(char *word) {
  int index, len;  //declares 2 integer variables
  char temp;       //creates a temporary char variable
  len = length(word); //set the length variable to the length of the word
  for (index=0; index<len/2; index++) {
    //Loop through the function, starting at 
    //index 0, going half way through the length of the word
    temp = word[index]; //save the character at the index
    word[index] = word[len-1-index]; //set the character at the index in the array 
                                     //to the reciprocal character.
    word[len-1-index] = temp; //Now set the reciprocal character to the saved one.
  }
}

//This essentially moves the first letter to the end, the 2nd letter to the 2nd 
//to end, etc.
```

So if you have the word "race" it swaps the "r" with the "e" and then the "a" with the "c" to get a final string of "ecar", or race backwards.

To understand why they need 3 assignments: if you set `word[index] = word[len-1-index]` then in both places, the same character exists. This would be like setting "race" to "racr". If you then set `word[len-1-index] = word[index]`, you would just be putting the same character back in the first part, so you would go from "racr" to "racr". You need a temporary variable to save the original value so you can replace the character at the front of the string.

Comment: It must be C 101, not C++ 101; this is a C question!

Comment: Lol, valid. Do they even offer C classes at colleges anymore? They didn't when I went.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (index=0; index<len/2; index++) {
1    temp = word[index];
2    word[index] = word[len-1-index];
3    word[len-1-index] = temp;
  }
```

1: store the value of `word[index]` (we'll need it later)

2: store the value of the word array that is equidistant from the midpoint of the array into `word[index]`

3: store the original value of `word[index]` into the position equidistant from the midpoint of the array

e.g.: if `index = 0`, the first word is exchanged with the last and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the code but not the question, the question was in regards to the last paragraph.